# $_SESSION Variable and AJAX Form - Variable Update Issue

Tags: php, ajax, session, session-variables

I searched around and couldn't find an answer to this specific question. I have a contact form that I'm using as an RSVP form that I've based off this tutorial: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/build-a-neat-html5-powered-contact-form/

The action on that form goes to a PHP script that writes the data to a database and sends some emails. It is done through AJAX. Database interaction and emails work just fine.

I'm using $_SESSION to bring variables back to the form once the data is posted so I can check errors and use conditionals. The problem is that this session data only seems to be available when I hit the submit button a **second** time.

I'll try to explain the problem succinctly:

1. I select a value from the drop-down menu for rsvp and press submit. The value from that selection that I've stored in a $_SESSION variable is not echoed back when I test it.
2. I Select a **different** value from the same dropdown menu and press submit again. The **FIRST** value is echoed back from that $_SESSION variable.

Here is my submit.php file. I've left a bunch of it out but I think this is the important stuff:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php require_once("includes/connection.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("includes/functions.php"); ?>
<?php
if(isset($_POST)) {
    //form validation vars
    $formok = true;
    $errors = array();  
    //sumbission data
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $date = date('Y-m-d');
    $time = date('H:i:s');
    $timestamp = $date . " " . $time;   
    //form data
    $firstname = mysql_prep($_POST['firstname']);
    $lastname = mysql_prep($_POST['lastname']);
    $dinner = mysql_prep($_POST['dinner']);
    $reqsong = mysql_prep($_POST['reqsong']);
    $email = mysql_prep($_POST['email']);
    $rsvp = mysql_prep($_POST['rsvp']);
    $message = mysql_prep($_POST['message']);
    //what we need to return back to our form
    $returndata = array(
        'posted_form_data' => array(
            'firstname' => $firstname,
            'lastname' => $lastname,
            'dinner' => $dinner,
            'reqsong' => $reqsong,
            'email' => $email,
            'rsvp' => $rsvp,
            'message' => $message
        ),
        'form_ok' => $formok,
        'errors' => $errors
     );
```

Then here is my rsvp.php form:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<div id="contact-form" class="clearfix">            
            <?php
                //init variables
                $cf = array();
                $sr = false;            
                if(isset($_SESSION['cf_returndata'])){
                    $cf = $_SESSION['cf_returndata'];
                    $sr = true;
                }
            ?>
        <ul id="errors" class="<?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok']) ? 'visible' : ''; ?>">
            <li id="info">There were some problems with your form submission:</li>
            <?php 
            if(isset($cf['errors']) && count($cf['errors']) > 0) :
                foreach($cf['errors'] as $error) :
            ?>
            <li><?php echo $error ?></li>
            <?php
                endforeach;
            endif;
            ?>
        </ul>
   <?php if($cf['posted_form_data']['rsvp'] == "Will Attend"): ?>
            <p id="success" class="<?php echo ($sr && $cf['form_ok']) ? 'visible' : ''; ?>">Thank you for your RSVP! <br> You will receive an email with additional information soon. <br><br> If your invitation was addressed to more than one person, please enter their information and submit again. <br><br> We look forward to seeing you soon!</p>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if($cf['posted_form_data']['rsvp'] == "Will Not Attend"): ?>
            <p id="success" class="<?php echo ($sr && $cf['form_ok']) ? 'visible' : ''; ?>">Too bad you can't make it.</p>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <form method="post" action="submit.php">
            <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" value="<?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok']) ? $cf['firstname'] : '' ?>" placeholder="First Name" required autofocus />
            <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" value="<?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok']) ? $cf['lastname'] : '' ?>" placeholder="Last Name" required autofocus />
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="<?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok']) ? $cf['email'] : '' ?>" placeholder="Email Address" required />          
            <select id="rsvp" name="rsvp">
                <option value="Will Attend">Will Attend</option>
                <option value="Will Not Attend">Will Not Attend</option>
            </select>
            <select id="dinner" name="dinner">
                <option value="select">Dinner Selection</option>
                <option value="Chicken" <?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok'] && $cf['posted_form_data']['dinner'] == 'Chicken') ? "selected='selected'" : '' ?>>Chicken</option>
                <option value="Pork" <?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok'] && $cf['posted_form_data']['dinner'] == 'Pork Fillet') ? "selected='selected'" : '' ?>>Pork</option>
            </select>                
            <input type="reqsong" id="reqsong" name="reqsong" value="<?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok']) ? $cf['posted_form_data']['reqsong'] : '' ?>" placeholder="Request a Song to be Played!"/>
            <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Leave us a message if you like! If you have any allergies or dietary needs, please indicate them here."><?php echo ($sr && !$cf['form_ok']) ? $cf['posted_form_data']['message'] : '' ?></textarea>                
            <span id="loading"></span>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit-button" />
        </form>
        <?php unset($_SESSION['cf_returndata']); ?>
    </div>
```

Sorry for the large amount of code here. Any ideas you have would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that you always get a posted value, which is not always the case.

Make sure to check what is actually posted:

```
$firstname = isset($_POST['firstname']) ? $_POST['firstname'] : false;
$lastname = isset($_POST['lastname']) ? $_POST['lastname'] : false;
// And so on.
```

Now, you can do something like this:

```
$noLastname = "Last name not found.";
if(!($name)){ $_SESSION['errorMessage'] .= $noLastname; }else{ $_SESSION['lastname'] = $lastname; }
```

So I think you're over-complexing your code by constructing that array, just work with individual sessions, you might be storing some null values in it and that's just pointless.

An example of how you can use it:

```
<input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['firstname'])){echo $_SESSION['firstname'];}else{echo '';}?>" placeholder="First Name" required autofocus />
```

Terminate the array, make sure that you're actually using data that exist, and so on. You will see the light.

Comment: Thank you for those suggestions. I implemented them but the problem persists. This specific problem seems like its more an issue of when the session data becomes available. For instance, when I do a test case and simply try to echo back a value stored in a session variable, it isn't until I refresh the page that I can see that value echoed back. Is there away to access it immediately after I submit the form? A reminder - it submits with AJAX.